# securing sql queries against malicious intent

Tags: mysqli, cross-domain, security

For prototyping, I often use a self-built plugin where i an do something like this

```
$.databaseContents({
   url: '/sqliquery.php',
   data : {query : 'SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = 45'}
});
```

The php script will execute the query and return a JSON-encoded result.

In a localhost environment I obviously don't worry about securing my server from malicious intent.

So I wonder, what would I best do if I actually wanted to deploy this on a live website? I'm not keen on doing a lot of unnecessary security engineering - it's not like I'm going to be getting 12,000 hits a day. But I'd like to be sure that I don't end up having my database injected with nasty queries.

After some reading, my impression is that I can simply secure the php query variable by doing `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["query"]);` but that seems not really safe - Can't someone just directly interact with a php script and submit data by spoofing the host or something? I'm not very familiar with this stuff.

I thought maybe allowing only a specific URL to access it would be good. Or is can that be circumvented easily?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I wonder, what would I best do if I actually wanted to deploy this on a live website?

That's simple

#### Quit this approach of creating queries on the client side.

And create them like **everyone** does it - on the **server side** only. Using **prepared statements** to represent whatever dynamical data in the query.

So - write your queries with placeholders in the server-side script, then send **only data** from client, then bind this data to prepared statement and then run your query.

#### That's the only way.

Comment: Hm. I guess I expected this kind of answer, and I realize I need to re-phrase the question: if you're malicious hacker and looking at a 2-bit website, it's not that hard to simply guess the query above. I'm serious: the likelihood of the table being called `members` and the form data variable names being the same as the column names are high. Given that scenario, how do I properly prevent injection attempts?